# custom table td witdh

Tags: css

The problem :
[image: The image]

HTML

```
<div class="visible-sm visible-xs " id="aatablet" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:10px; text-align: center;">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="item_title">
                    <div style="padding-top:5px;">
                        Available at:
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <img src="img/amazon-lrg.gif" alt="amazon" />

                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="img/ebay-lrg.gif" alt="ebay" />
                </td>
                <td >
                    <img src="img/tomatomill-lrg.gif" alt="tomatomill" />
                </td>
                <td ><img src="img/BBG-lrg.gif" alt="BBG" />
                </td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>    
                    <td >
                 </td>            
                <td>
                    <img src="img/sears-lrg.gif" alt="sears" />
                </td>                 
                <td >
                    <img src="img/healthcraft-home-logo.gif" alt="Healthcraft" title="Healthcraft" />
                </td>
                 <td >
                     <img src="img/paradisecozycabins.jpg" alt="paradisecozycabins" title="paradisecozycabins" />

                 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 #aatablet > table {
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Framework:bootstrap 3.4.

I want to make td of tomato logo width 100px not 178px like Helt Craft and td of Paradise(last td) 50px not 150px like BIGGAME.
Can someone help me ?I'm not good at making custom tables.Is it possible to do it whit only CSS?
Ty all.

Comment: please post the code you are working on...

Comment: code i'm working on posted.

Comment: see `table-layout: fixed` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: You're using a `<table>` all the cells in a column (the cells with the 'tomato logo' and the 'Health Craft') will be the same size. This is expected behaviour from a `<table>` element. If you need different sizes, don't use tables.

Comment: I know that,so there is no way to change that ?Can someone post a code that will get the same effect without <table> :S

Comment: You could use `colspan`, perhaps, but you'd be far *far* better off letting go of the `<table>` element and using, for example, an unordered ([`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)) or ordered ([`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)) list.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create multiple tables, but then that's a *little* messy

Comment: or even see flexboxes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give `inline:block` for td and give separate widths. Target each `td` using `:nth-of-type`

```
td{
  display: inline-block;
}

tr:first-child td:nth-of-type(3){
  width: 100px;
}
tr:last-child td:nth-of-type(4){
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It won't work in IE9 because this version won't let you change display on `td` but it's now pretty old and apart from corporate and B2B websites, you may ignore it I guess